# Getting rid of thousands of widgets on a plasma desktop

Tags: kde-plasma

I think my trackpad malfunctioned and pressed the middle button on my plasma desktop maybe a thousand times. As a result, I have about a thousand (you guessed it) empty post-it notes icons all across my desktop.

Removing them one by one will take forever. I tried doing the following

`mv ~/.local/share/plasma_notes /tmp/foo`

but that doesn't seem to be making a difference.

For reference, here's what a small portion of my desktop looks like.

[image: for reference, here's a small portion of my desktop]

Answer (score 1):

Removing entries from `./plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` did the trick.